# C - linker error

Tags: c, xcode, linker

I write a C program with Xcode 4. I include some OpenSSL header files:

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
```

This does not seem to work, as I get `Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error: "..." referenced from:` errors.

I have tried to include the OpenSSL framework, but I cannot find it in the list (I only find `libssl` which doesn't do the trick). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#include` is relevant at the preprocessing/compiling phase. Since you’re getting linker errors, the problem is that you haven’t linked the appropriate libraries.

OpenSSL is not a framework in the Apple sense, which is why you haven’t found it. In your case, since libssl wasn't enough, you’re missing libcrypto (which is also part of OpenSSL).